# Unity's Custom Inspector Enum field to conditionally allow some enum values and not others

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have two enums.

The first is PrimaryColor which can be "Red, Yellow, or Blue"

The second is TertiaryColor which can be "Red, Magenta, Purple, Violet, Blue, etc"

I want my custom inspector to show only a subset of possible values to choose for the second enum based on the value of the first enum. So if it was Blue, I would want the user to be able to choose from "purple, violet, teal, magenta, blue," but not red/orange/etc.

I found that there is an option in the custom inspector "checkEnabled" that sounds like it would be perfect for this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup.html

However I'm not able to get it to compile when attempting to use this field.

Could anyone give me an example on how to go about using the checkEnabled field of EnumPopUp to do this?  I can get the enumPopup method to work just fine with the basic parameters passing it a string and enum, however when I attempt to pass it the custom function method it says that all of the parameters can't be converted into GUIlayoutoptions.

```
//The variation of the method I am attempting to run
public static Enum EnumPopup(GUIContent label, Enum selected, Func<Enum,bool> checkEnabled, 
bool includeObsolete, params GUILayoutOption[] options);
```

```
MyColor myColor = (MyColor)target;
Func<TertiaryColorEnum, bool> showEnumValue = ShowEnumValue;
GUIContent label = new GUIContent("Color");

//this call gives me a red line under every paramater even though they should all be what it needs
myColor.tertiaryColor = (TertiaryColorEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(label, myColor.tertiaryColor,
showEnumValue, true);

//these ones work just fine (other parameter sets for the method)
myColor.tertiaryColor = (TertiaryColorEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(myColor.tertiaryColor);
myColor.tertiaryColor = (TertiaryColorEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("hi", myColor.tertiaryColor);
myColor.tertiaryColor = (TertiaryColorEnum)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(label, myColor.tertiaryColor);


// my custom function
public static bool ShowEnumValue(TertiaryColorEnum tertiaryColorEnum)
{  
    if(myColor.primaryColor == PrimaryColorEnum.Red)
    {
       if(tertiaryColorEnum == TertiaryColorEnum.Purple)
           return false;
       else
           return true;
    }
}
```

My best guess is that I'm doing something wrong with the Func parameter it wants, but I don't see how.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ShowEnumValue has to accept an **Enum**. You can then cast the Enum to **TertiaryColorEnum** within the function and operate on it, but otherwise your function doesn't match the **Func< Enum, bool>** prototype, so the compiler matches the call to the next appropriate prototype:

```
public static Enum EnumPopup(string label, Enum selected, params GUILayoutOption[] options);
```

It's like if you had a delegate that accepted a specific type/class (e.g. Animal) and you tried to give it one that accepted a derived class (e.g. Lion) - the delegate expects a function that can handle crocodiles too!

[Some reading on the topic of Covariance and Contravariance if you're interested.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: Thanks so much, no idea why that didn't occur to me, changing it to taking an enum and casting it works perfectly.